# how to remove missing field names from picklist field .refer to the image attached

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, aura, object

[image]

how to remove this missing label from list. I am sending a map containing all the objects of the salesforce org from apex and sending it to the component.

```
     @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static  Map<String,String> getObjectList(){
            List<schema.sObjectType> allObjects = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();
        
        Map<String,String> objectMap=new Map<String,String>();
        for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
            objectMap.put(objTyp+'',objTyp.getDescribe().getLabel());
        }    
        System.debug('list of object'+objectMap);
      for(string target : objectMap.values()) 
      { System.debug('*************** Current Name: ' + target); }

      for(string target : objectMap.keySet()) 
      { System.debug('*************** Current Key: ' + target); }
        return objectMap;
           
}
```

Comment: what do you intend to do with the object names in picklist values? The describe call with return all the objects, you may want to filter the list to show only the required objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an internal platform issue. If you're able to reproduce this behavior across multiple orgs, please open a support case to report the bug and include detailed reproduction steps.

If you just want to make this visually go away, remove the `ChannelProgramMember` sObject from your map.